# how to open a a pdf file using fileinfo object of System.IO

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0, system.io.fileinfo

I have mafe a simple object using `fileInfo` class as:

```
DirectoryInfo myDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(@"d:\Books");
FileInfo[] files = myDirectory.GetFiles();

foreach (FileInfo file in files)
{
    try
    {
        file.OpenRead();
        break;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString());
    }
}
```

The first file in the directory(Books) is `PDF`. The code throw no exception. Still the particular file doesn't open. what code i am missing or i am doing any error. Thanks for any assistence.

Comment: What do you mean *particular file doesn't open*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `Process.Start` to open files in default application, if you open `pdf` file, it will open in *Adobe Reader* if *Adobe Reader* is default application for `pdf`:

```
 Process.Start(file.FullName);
```

[`FileInfo.OpenRead`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.openread.aspx) returns a read-only `FileStream` object, not for opening file.

Comment: thanks sir. it works now. but Why does the file.OpenRead() doesn't work in above code.??